Show these error . Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' or '. :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets' or :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
:app:cleanMergeDebugAssets

These errors are displayed.
Each time you do a Flutter run, you will see one of these three.
I could not build by manually deleting the .gradlew file.
The android file is almost identical to the default one in the Flutter project.
Slightly different is that the Admob code is included.
$flutter run                  7s


Changing current working directory to: /StudioProjects/xxx
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Unable to delete file '/StudioProjects/xxx/build/app/generated/source/buildConfig/debug'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              5.6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

